# how to disable zooming for mobile view but enable it in desktop view

Tags: html, css

I am using two stylesheets for different screen sizes i.e

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/style.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen and (min-width:285px) and (max-width: 400px)' href='style/m-style.css' />
```

So I want to disable zooming for the 2nd link and enable it for the 1st one. Can i use two meta tags one for each?
Thanks.